# Python word client cannot find .dotx

Tags: python, python-3.6

Python cannot currently find my file.

```
import os
import win32com.client 

word=win32com.client.Dispatch("Word.Application")
word.Documents.Open('Test_template')
```

I am getting `'Sorry we can't find your file'`.

When I run

```
import os
print(os.listdir('.'))
```

I can see `'Test_template.dotx'`.

When I change

```
word.Documents.Open('Test_template')
```

to

```
word.Documents.Open('Test_template.dotx')
```

I get the same error

Comment: idk why are you opening ms word template file at first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue ended up being a Citrix connection that masked the true file location. So the path appeared correct but was incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a directory specified here (although the fact that os.listdir() returns the item seems encouraging), but try specifying the full directory path, like this:

```
word.Documents.Open('//folder_1/folder_2/Test_template.dotx')

# You could also specify the working directory explicitly with os, as in:
os.chdir('//folder_1/folder_2')
```

And double-check that the filename matches exactly - I have definitely hit these errors with a single letter that was supposed to be lower vs. uppercase.